# List any file ending with .in and corresponding .out with shell script

Tags: shell, scripting, ls

I have a directory full of files ending with different extensions, how would I list/select only the files ending with `.in` and corresponding `.out` that share the same basename?

e.g.

```
file1.txt
file1.in
file2.in
file3.in
file2.out
file3.out
```

What I want to select from these files are:

```
file2.in
file2.out
file3.in
file3.out
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you want `.in` to be paired with `.out`, loop through only `*.in` and check if there is a corresponding `.out` file, if so, print out both:

```
for f in *.in; do
  if [[ -f ${f%.in}.out ]]; then
    echo $f
    echo ${f%.in}.out
  fi
done
```

Comment: This is how I would have done it. Sweet and simple. I'd simplify it to one line though: `for f in *.in; do [[ -e ${f%.in}.out ]] && echo $f ${f%.in}.out; done`

Answer (score 3):

First match against all files, and check if .out file exists, then print the name:

```
for x in *; do
   if [[ "$x" =~ ^(.*)\.in ]] && [[ -f ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.out ]];then 
      echo -n "$x ${x%%.in}.out "; 
   fi
done
echo
```

Comment: Daaaayumn. I had no idea BASH could save substrings to a variable like that. That `BASH_REMATCH` array is awesome. Niiice! PS: You could simplify that into one `[[ ... && ... ]]` expression.

Comment: @ryran, [[ ... ]] & [[ ... ]] is guaranteed to be processed left-to-right. Are you sure that [[ ... && ... ]] is also so guaranteed? (Not so interesting if it merely happens now to be so processed in the current version of bash.)

Comment: @dubiousjim: Yes, I'm sure that `[[ ... && ...]]` is processed as expected. Take a look at the bash man page under the `[[ expression ]]` section.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to only select the "*.in" files, e.g. "for x in *.in; do" rather than selecting all files and then checking if the file ends with ".in"?

Answer (score 2):

With zsh:

```
has_out() [[ -e $REPLY:r.out ]]
ls -ld -- *.in(+has_out)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can list all those files, remove the extensions, filter duplicates and print them:

```
$ ls | grep '\(\.in\|.out\)$' | sed 's/....$//' \
     | sort | uniq -c | grep '^[\t ]*2' | sed 's/^[\t ]\+2 //'
```

Advantages:

- does not need bash
- does just one expensive operation - directory listing - i.e. does not need to [stat(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) each file (as in `[[ -f ... ]]`)

In case the `ls` already alphabetically sorts its output the `sort` command can be removed from the pipe. I don't know if POSIX specifies the sorting behavior of a `ls`.

The pipe prints all the basenames if files with `.in` and `.out` extension.

If you then need a list of the corresponding files you have to suffix the list with the previously filtered extensions. For example like this:

```
$ ls | grep '\(\.in\|.out\)$' | sed 's/....$//' \
     | sort | uniq -c | grep '^[\t ]*2' \
     | sed -e 's/^[\t ]\+2 //' -e 's/$/.in/ ; p; s/in$/out/'
```